# User Alerts for a SharePoint List

Tags: alert, notifications

Is there a way to see who received alerts at the list level?  I know you can see/view alerts for other people on a site, but I am interested in being able to see specifically who is receiving alerts for a list on a site.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in C# (server object model)

```
public static string listarAlertasLista(SPWeb web, string listaInternalName)
{
    string alerts = "";
    string listUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + listaInternalName;
    listUrl = listUrl.Replace("//", "/");

    SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
    SPAlertCollection alertsColl = web.Alerts;

    alerts += "<span style='color: blue'>Alertas de la lista " + listaInternalName + "</span><br>";
    foreach (SPAlert alert in alertsColl)
    {
        if (alert.ListID == list.ID)
        {
            alerts += "User: " + alert.User.LoginName + "<br>";
            alerts += "Type: " + alert.AlertType + "<br>";
            alerts += "Chanel: " + alert.DeliveryChannels.ToString() + "<br>";
        }
    }

    return alerts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As OOTB there's no solution to get specifically who is receiving alerts for a list on a site.

you can Get all alerts based on specific User from

- Site Settings > Site Administration > User Alerets > Filter By user.

[image]

As a workaround you can use code as @jpussacq mentioned

Or without code from `Content Database` and filter using `ListTitle`

```
SELECT        TOP (1000) UserInfo.tp_Title as UserName,  ImmedSubscriptions.SiteUrl + ImmedSubscriptions.WebUrl AS Site, ImmedSubscriptions.WebTitle, ImmedSubscriptions.ListTitle, 
                         ImmedSubscriptions.ListBaseType, ImmedSubscriptions.AlertTitle, ImmedSubscriptions.AlertType, ImmedSubscriptions.AlwaysNotifyBit, ImmedSubscriptions.SystemBit, ImmedSubscriptions.Status

FROM            ImmedSubscriptions INNER JOIN
                         UserInfo ON ImmedSubscriptions.UserId = UserInfo.tp_ID
WHERE        (ImmedSubscriptions.ListTitle = 'Doc')
```

**OutPut**

[image]

To show it in SharePoint try to [use external List](https://blog.devoworx.net/2011/08/19/create-external-content-type/)

**Note**: It's heavily recommended to don't modify anything at Content Database so try to create a view in another database , and create external content type using SharePoint Designer then external list to show it within SharePoint without code.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with examples shown at [Create - Edit - Find - Delete SharePoint Alerts using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/11/managing-alerts-using-powershell.html), I use the following when looking for alerts on a single list.

```
    ##### Display All alerts for a Particular List within a Site Collection ########

    # Url of the site collection you want to check
    $spSiteUrl = "https://webapp.domain.com/sites/test"

    # Display Name of the web you want to check
    $spWebName = "Web Blah Blah Blah"

    # Display Name of the List/Library you are looking for
    $spListName = "List Blah Blah Blah" 

    # Obtain all alerts in the list/library
    $spAlerts = Get-SPSite -Identity $spSiteUrl `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AllWebs `
    | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq $spWebName } `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lists `
    | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq $spListName }

    foreach ($spAlert in $spAlerts.ParentWeb.Alerts) {

        $spAlert | Select-Object `
        @{Name="User Display Name";Expression={$_.User.Name}}, `
        @{Name="Title";Expression={$_.Title}}, `
        @{Name="Frequency";Expression={$_.AlertFrequency}}, `
        @{Name="Delivery Methods";Expression={$_.DeliveryChannels}}, `
        @{Name="Change Type";Expression={$_.eventtype}} `
        | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Documents\ListAlerts.csv" -Append

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Variables
$WebURL = "http://YourWebUrl"
$ListName="YourListName"

#Function to Get All Active Alerts on a Given List
Function Get-ListAlerts($WebURL, $ListName)
{
  #Get the Web and List objects
  $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
  $List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

  #Get All Alerts created in the list - Which are Active
  $ListAlerts = $Web.Alerts | Where-Object {($_.List.Title -eq $List.Title) -and ($_.Status -eq "ON")}

  foreach($Alert in $ListAlerts)
  {
          write-host "Alert' - $($Alert.Title)' Created for User - '$($Alert.User.Name)'"
  }

 #Dispose web object
 $Web.Dispose()
}
```